# device is not connected

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

i am very new to window phone application development. i have just write a simple code of button click.but when i try to run it, it shows error like "Device is not connected" but when i connected to internet my application run. is it essential to connected to the internet to run my application.
i don't have window phone.
i have just downloaded the window sdk 7.0 which automatically installed window phone emulator.
i don't have window phone . what should i do ?
this is my code

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Button Name="_playaudio" Height="80" Width="150" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="_playaudio_Click">
                <Button.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDB2422" Offset="0.36" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFAD3A3A" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Button.Background> Click Me
            </Button>
            <MediaElement x:Name="mymedia" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Source="/assest/Audio/Animals/Lion.wav" Volume="100" AutoPlay="False" >

            </MediaElement>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to be connected to any network in order to make it run.
The error you get is due to the debug device you selected.

On the top bar of Visual Studio there is a button with a green triangle on it, on the right you probably see the caption "Device". Use the dropdown menu to select an emulator instead of the phisical device. When you hit on the button, the emulator will open, the app will be installed and then will be launched.

Comment: sir now it is working fine , but when i clicked on button then i can't hear any music.

Comment: First enable hardware keyboard inside the emulator. To do so, browse somewhere on the emulator UI, then press PAGE UP button on your keyboard. To turn up emulator volume use F9 key. MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff754352(v=vs.105).aspx If this is not enough, the problem is with your code. As I can see, the path of that file includes "/assest/", maybe you meant "Assets"? And also you do not need te first slash

Comment: no no sir my folder name is assest. i didn't get you here "browse somewhere on the emulator UI, then press PAGE UP button on your keyboard.".
and also i removed the first slash form code.but still i can't listen the music

Comment: this is my code on button click 
private void _playaudio_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mymedia.Play();
        }

Comment: You should check if Source property is correct, so check that the path to the .wav file is correct

Answer (score 1):

You dont require internet or physical device to build or debug application. Make sure the targetted debug platform is emulator and not the device. That should solve the issue.